What kind of simulation should I run to find out the temperature at which a crystal would melt?
I have learned some basics as far as performing molecular dynamics simulations, but struggle to figure out big-picture issues.
I would like to know if it's possible to find out the temperature at which a solid would melt.  If I started out with the coordinates of atoms that make up a single crystal cell, is there a standard technique for finding out melting temperature?
Thank you.

I think the right path to follow is using molecular dynamics for different temperatures.

@Camps, so, for example, running a set of NVT simulations on a crystal and gradually increasing the temperature?  Do you know what I would need to look at to figure out whether melting had happened? Thank you.

+1 but I have just limited your post to 1 question to comply with our 1 question per post policy.

To find out the melting temperature, the easiest way is to do an MD simulation with temperature ramping. You should be able to find examples on how to do it in LAMMPS for LJ spheres. To find if a structure has melted,the best way is to compute RDFs and structure factors. If you have more questions, please write to me.

@HemanthHaridas, that's very kind.  Thank you.  I will take a look at the LAMMPS documentation and may then take you up on your kind offer.  I have seen changes in RDFs as temperature has changed, so I'm curious about how those kinds of changes might be distinguishable from melting.  I will try to figure it out!

Depends a bit on your exact system, but one way is to immerse your crystal in its own melt, and scan temperatures both ways (i.e. from hot to cold, and vice versa). When the crystal grows, you are below the melting temperature. When the melt grows, you've passed the Tm.

@Bdrs, thank you for that.  I have no idea what that's about, but will search around online.  I don't want to impose, but if you have time to provide a for-dummies-type explanation, how would that work?  I.e., I assume I'd be running an NVT (constant temperature) simulation.  So how would I define distinct temperatures within one cell?

@NTS, I personally have a policy that I would not answer questions on any SE sites (partly because of how the data would be used). If you have more questions, please write to me. You can find my contact details on my profile page.
